# Does anyone with AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess policy can read my DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

Maybe it's a dumb question, but I'd like to *hide* my DynamoDB so that only the AWS users that I generated can access this table.

In case of MySQL, I can safeguard my DB by requiring username and password even when the IP and DB name are exposed.

```
from mysql.connector import connect

cnx = connect(user='alice', password='abc', host='localhost', database='people')
```

Suppose some outside AWS users know the ARN of my DynamoDB table and they have `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` policy. Then can they read my table data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if they have 'AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess' access, they only have it for their databases, not your database(s).